# How can I speed up compilation of Flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3, flashdevelop

My Flex project has six sub-projects. How can I speed up compilation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a compiler other than `mxmlc`.

Flex Builder has a built-in compiler that uses incremental compilation, resulting in large performance gains (`mxmlc` compiles everything from scratch and loads up the JVM each time).

The Flex SDK includes a "compiler shell" called `fcsh` that allows you to do incremental compilation, but the problem is that you can't use it like `mxmlc`; you need to enter an interactive shell and issue custom commands to incrementally compile your projects. I've written a wrapper shell script ([`fcshctl`](http://hasseg.org/blog/post/194/fcshctl-the-flex-compiler-shell-controller/)) that allows you to use `fcsh` like `mxmlc` and there are a bunch of other wrappers that do more or less the same thing in different ways.

Comment: Um, mxmlc in the current Flex 3 and up SDKs have incremental compilation support; just pass 
`-incremental=true`

Comment: @rakslice Good point. Running `mxmlc` still needs to load up the JVM each time, though (while `fcsh` stays resident and is thus faster).